# Renovate config "automerge" could not work

Tags: package.json, renovate

I use Renovate for update package.json

refs:

- [Renovate Docs \| Renovate Docs](https://docs.renovatebot.com/)

This is my `renovate.json` file, but `patch` directive is not work, I must merge it manually now. (`schedule` directive is work)

```
{
  "extends": ["config:base"],
  "timezone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "schedule": ["every weekend"],
  "patch": { "automerge": true }
}
```

I should set like below?

```
{
  "automerge": true,
  "major": { "automerge": false },
  "minor": { "automerge": false }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify which types of updates you want to auto-merge. This is the example from the docs:

```
{
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "updateTypes": ["minor", "patch", "pin", "digest"],
      "automerge": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Example from: https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#automerge

So your config should look like:

```
{
  "extends": ["config:base"],
  "timezone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "schedule": ["every weekend"],
  "packageRules": [
        {
          "updateTypes": ["patch", "pin", "digest"],
          "automerge": true
        }
      ]
}
```

Comment: wow, thx your answer, awesome! (sorry for my rep to late

Comment: Worth noting, from the [docs](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#automergetype):

If you prefer that Renovate more silently automerge without Pull Requests at all, you can configure `"automergeType": "branch"`.